# how to convert list to dictionary form?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, ordereddictionary

```py
dic_list = [{'a': '123456789',
             'b': '',
             'c': '1',
             'd': '',
             'e': '',
             'f': '',
             'e': '',
             'g': '',
             'h': '',
             'Total': '1'}, {'a': '123456710',
             'b': '',
             'c': '1',
             'd': '',
             'e': '',
             'f': '',
             'e': '',
             'g': '',
             'h': '',
             'Total': '1'}, ...]
```

I want to make above dictionaries to below dictionary form. There are many dictionaries not just one like above. Actually, when i write "type(dict_list)", it says list. I don't know why it says list. Also i want to get "Pearson Correlation Coefficient".

```py
dic_list = {'123456789': {
  'b': '',
  'c': 1,
  'd': '',
  'e': '',
  'f': '',
  'g': '',
  'h': '',
  'i': '',
  'Total': '1',},
{'123456710': {
  'b': '',
  'c': 1,
  'd': '',
  'e': '',
  'f': '',
  'g': '',
  'h': '',
  'i': '',
  'Total': '1',}....,
```

Comment: everything with [ ] around it is a list. This is a list with multiple dictionaries in it. If you need ordered dictionaries (because you tagged it, not sure in the context why you would need it). You might want to take a look at collections.OrderedDict: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Comment: What is the logic of moving from first list of dictionaries to suggested output?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do, more broadly? As you've written it here, this question is unclear.

Comment: `type(dict_list)` returns list because it's actually a `list` not `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Python3.6 and dictionary comprehension

```
dic_list = {i['a']: {j: k for j, k in i.items() if j!='a'} for i in dic_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this should work. Test this and let me know.

```
big_dict = {}
for i in dic_list:
    k = i['a']
    del i['a']
    big_dict[k] = dict(i) 
print(big_dict)
```

Comment: it goes like

{'123456789': OrderedDict(['b', ' '), ('c', '1'), ('d', ' '), ('e', ' '), ('f', ' '), ('e', ' '), ('g', ' '), ('h', ' '), ('Total', '1')]), '123456710' : OrderedDict([(  ......

that's little bit  different which i asked.. and my computer memory can not afford to run this code T.T. this is first time that my computer woriking like this

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that all values in `a` in each of your dictionary inside `dic_list` are unique, you can use dict comprehension as below

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> customer = {x.pop('a'):x for x in deepcopy(dic_list)}
>>> print(customer)

{'123456789': {'b': '', 'c': '1', 'd': '', 'e': '', 'f': '', 'g': '', 'h': '', 'Total': '1'}, 
'123456710': {'b': '', 'c': '1', 'd': '', 'e': '', 'f': '', 'g': '', 'h': '', 'Total': '1'}}
```

if you don't take a deep copy your original list will be modified

**Edit** : Pearson correlation

```
import math

def isfloat(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def sim_pearson(data, name1, name2):
    X = [v for k,v in data.get(name1).items() if k in data.get(name2).keys()]
    Y = [v for k,v in data.get(name2).items() if k in data.get(name1).keys()]

    # convert string to float if convertable, else replace with zero
    X = [float(i) if isfloat(i) else 0 for i in X]
    Y = [float(i) if isfloat(i) else 0 for i in Y]

    count = len(X)
    sumX = sum(X)
    sumY = sum(Y)
    sumPowX = sum([i**2 for i in X])
    sumPowy = sum([i**2 for i in Y])
    sumXY = sum([i*j for i,j in zip(X,Y)])
    return ( sumXY- ((sumX*sumY)/count) )/ math.sqrt( (sumPowX - (pow(sumX,2) / count)) * (sumPowy - (pow(sumY,2)/count)))

sim_pearson(customer,'123456789','123456710')
# here 'customer' is the dictionary you have created earlier
```

you can calculate Pearson correlation coefficien using [scipy.stats.pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html#scipy-stats-pearsonr)

Comment: thank you there are 1 more question. i want to get Pearson Correlation Coefficient. so when i put the code which is below, i doesn't work. could you tell me why? (it say key error: "123456789" and customer is my csv file name)

Comment: def sim_pearson(data, name1, name2):
    sumX=0 
    sumY=0 
    sumPowX=0 
    sumPowY=0 
    sumXY=0 
    count=0 
    
    for i in data[name1]: 
        if i in data[name2]:
            sumX+=data[name1][i]
            sumY+=data[name2][i]
            sumPowX+=pow(data[name1][i],2)
            sumPowY+=pow(data[name2][i],2)
            sumXY+=data[name1][i]*data[name2][i]
            count+=1
    
    return ( sumXY- ((sumX*sumY)/count) )/ sqrt( (sumPowX - (pow(sumX,2) / count)) * (sumPowY - (pow(sumY,2)/count)))

sim_pearson(customer,'123456789','123456710')

Comment: values in your dictionary may be strings, not integers or float

Comment: it says "None Type" object has no attribute 'items'.  Do you know why?

Comment: your `data` which is coming to the function `sim_pearson(data, name1, name2)` , is blank, hence NoneType

Comment: i filled my non-type values by using 

customer[customer_columns] = customer[customer_columns].fillna(0)

but it says like this...

Comment: your `customer` itself is noneType, try printing it out. `None Type` doesnt mean `Na` values, it means the object itself is blank/None

Comment: I don't understand that I filled my customer.csv file blank data to 0. but it says the same error.